# How to Sum field and create two different field with different ids

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query i have a table screenshots below call ob and emp_data table

I want to get the sum of the field "date" as liv based on obCo=5 and another sum for same field and as late based on obCo=6. here is my query.

```
select ob.obNo,
  SUM(ob.date) as liv,
  ob.empId,
  ob.obDesc,    
  ob.lugar,
  ob.sponsor,
  ob.dFile,
  ob.obCo,
  emp_data.lname,
  emp_data.fname
from emp_data 
inner join ob on ob.empId=emp_data.emp_id
where obCo=5  
  and dFile >= '$year/05/01' 
  and dFile <='$nyear/04/31' and ak_id=1
group by ob.empId
order by lname ASC
```

Comment: Do you really want to **add dates**? You can try **DATE_ADD** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum an `IF()` expression.

```
select ob.obNo,
  SUM(if (obCo = 5, ob.date, 0)) as liv,
  SUM(if (obCo = 6, ob.date, 0)) as late,
  ob.empId,
  ob.obDesc,    
  ob.lugar,
  ob.sponsor,
  ob.dFile,
  ob.obCo,
  emp_data.lname,
  emp_data.fname
from emp_data 
inner join ob on ob.empId=emp_data.emp_id
where obCo IN (5, 6)
  and dFile >= '$year/05/01' 
  and dFile <='$nyear/04/31' and ak_id=1
group by ob.empId
order by lname ASC
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edbdd/2)

Comment: it does not execute query empty result sir @Barmar

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: here is the SQL file https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5zmXTs4bwSPajBiOGRQU05kS2M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you have `$year` and `$nyear` set to? Are there any rows that match all the criteria?

Comment: sir, i noticed on sqlfiddle demo that late was not computed

Comment: working.   and dFile >= '2013/05/01' 
  and dFile <='2014/04/31' and ak_id=1